# AngularJS: Method expression is not of Function type

Tags: angularjs, phpstorm, webstorm, jsdoc, jetbrains-ide

Having a class defined as:

```
angular.module('trip')
        /** @class MyClass */
        .factory('MyClass', [Factory]);

function Factory() {
   return function(){
         // fields & functions
   }
}
```

Then in the code I would instantiate a new object:

```
/**
 * @param {MyClass} MyClass
 */
function(MyClass){
   var myClass = new MyClass(); // HERE MyClass is highlighted in phpStorm
}
```

When calling `new MyClass();` the **MyClass** is highlighted in phpStorm and I get this warning:

> Method expression is not of Function type

What does it mean? How to get rid of it?

Comment: A very similar question was asked here without any comment either: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32778278/1075289

Comment: `.factory('MyClass', Factory);` (sans brackets)?

Comment: @GrahamPHeath The brackets are there because we use strict DI. So it ain't change anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

WebStorm (along with other tools) understands `/** @param {MyClass} MyClass */` as a declaration of an instance of MyClass. It says you can't instantiate an instance. I may only suggest to change JSDoc to `/** @param {function():MyClass} MyClass */` to cease the warning. JSDoc itself doesn't offer a better way to express a factory.

Also, please take a look at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17325.

Comment: Thx @de1mar, it's suppressing the warning and that's what I needed.

Comment: Thanks. Still relevant in 2021 for WebStorm.

Comment: This answer is relevant for PhpStorm 2022.3 too, thanks!